# Not able to set bandwidth in Android app using b=AS

Tags: android, webrtc

Have tried changing SDP in AppRTCDemo app for video to **b=AS:256**

Still it's not restricting it to 256kbps.

In webrtc-internals it shows bitsSentPerSecond around 256kbps, but bitsReceivedPerSecond is around 2mbps!

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateSuccess(final SessionDescription origSdp) {
      abortUnless(localSdp == null, "multiple SDP create?!?");
      String newSdpStr = origSdp.description.replace("a=mid:video", "a=mid:video\r\nb=AS:256");
      final SessionDescription sdp = new SessionDescription(
          origSdp.type, preferISAC(newSdpStr));
      localSdp = sdp;
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            pc.setLocalDescription(sdpObserver, sdp);
          }
        });
     }
```

Comment: You change it before you set it as the local description yes?

Comment: yes, before setting local description.

Comment: I believe the bandwidth flag needs to be on its own line. trying putting `\r\n` to do a carriage return after a=mid:video in the SDP.

Comment: I forgot to put it correctly here. In code it's there. Does it work on Android? Or just on Chrome?

Comment: I have had this work just fine in Chrome. It honestly SHOULD work on Chrome for Android.

Comment: Am trying on native Android app, not Chrome for Android.

Comment: Hey @sandeepd, any luck with bandwidth on Android app

Comment: @BugsHappen I did not try it later. I have set resolution to 320x240 to reduce the bandwidth, but that's not a solution.